# What's the Meaning of "the primary key is the data" in Columnar DB

Tags: hbase, column-oriented

While researching column-oriented DB, I read "the primary key is the data" many times. (e.g., at [Column-oriented DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS))

I thought I can randomly access to any cell (in a certain column) by value because values, the data, are already indexed as primary key.

But after I put more than 3M rows into HBase,
the HBase shell command

```
scan 'lottery', {COLUMNS => 'cf:status', FILTER => "ValueFilter(=, 'binary:win')"}
```

takes more than 3 seconds...

(It's getting slower and slower as more and more rows are put...)

`'win'` or `'lose'` are two possible values for the column `cf:status` and there is only 1 row whose value is `'win'`.

I might misunderstood...

What does "the primary key is the data" mean in column-oriented DB?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to find something quickly with HBase, it needs to be a prefix of the **rowkey**. Therefore *rowkey design* is of great importance when building for speed. For your case, you could use the values `'lottery_win'` or `'lottery_lose'` in the beginning of the rowkey of every row. This would make the query `scan 'lottery_win'` query very fast (sub-second), even with hundreds of billions of rows.

**Filters** in HBase are usually not very fast as the filter looks at *every row* that matches you scan. Having a filter read through millions of rows is generally not a good idea if you want speed.

*Primary key* in DBMS doesn't imply anything about performance. It is a constraint on the records you can put into a table. What gives the speed is an *index*. An HBase table only has one indexed item - and that is the rowkey. No other columns are indexed and therefore filters are slow (in the order of millions of rows per second).